# Data analysis before feeding to ML pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, python, datasets, data-preprocessing, r

I'm new to machine learning and I've been working through a dataset of ~3000 records with ~100 features. I've been hand rolling Python and R scripts to analyse the data. For example, plotting the distribution of each feature to see how normal it is, identify outliers, etc. Another example is plotting heatmaps of the features against themselves to identify strong correlations.

Whilst this has been a useful learning exercise, going forward I suspect there are tools that automate a lot of this data analysis for you, and produce the useful plots and possibly give recommendations on transforms, etc? I've had a search around but don't appear to be finding anything, I guess I'm not using the right terminology to find what I'm looking for.

If any useful open source tools for this kind of thing spring to mind that would be very helpful.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Artificial Intelligence SE. It seems to me that this question is off-topic here and would be better suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. Asking for tools or software libraries is generally off-topic here. You can read more about our scope on [our on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (basically, we focus on the theoretical, philosophical and social aspects of AI, so programming issues, including asking for tools, are generally excluded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question because indeed there are many tools out there to make this part of the process faster.
I have used as I usually stick to the following two:

- [Pandas profiling](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/rtd/)
- [Facets](https://pair-code.github.io/facets/)

You can also search for [alternatives](https://www.libhunt.com/r/pandas-profiling)
Hopefully, the community can help complement my answer.